# Парсинг страницы с помощью nokogiri

Tags: парсер, ruby, nokogiri

Есть некоторая страница([расписание](http://www.ifmo.ru/ru/schedule/0/B3107/raspisanie_zanyatiy_B3107.htm))

Есть необходимость вытащить необходимую информацию, например, предметы на день.

После некоторого "гугления" выбор парсера пал на Nokogiri. С помощью irb выяснил как достать все предметы **+ преподаватей** со всей страницы.

`irb(main):064:0> doc.css('.lesson').text.gsub(/\t/,'').gsub(/\r/,'').gsub(/\n/,'').strip
=> "Предмет/ПреподавательСоциально-политические проблемы современного общества (Прак) Борисов Олег СергеевичСоциально-политические проблемы современного общества (Лек) Борисов Олег Сергеевич ... Дополнительные главы физики (Прак) Рассадина Анна Александровна"`

Собственно, как вытащить информацию только по предметам на определенный день?

Comment: А зачем было делать `.gsub(/\t/,'').gsub(/\r/,'').gsub(/\n/,'')`?

Comment: Там много мусора было(по 15 табуляций подряд). почистил вывод. Знаю , что можно комплексно одной регуляркой, но дело не в этом

Comment: Дело в том, что вы неразбираемую ерунду получили из аккуратного структурированного HTML/XML. Приложите лучше вывод `puts doc.css('.lesson').to_s` UPD: хотя нет, лучше сделайте небольшую игрушечную HTML-страницу и на её примере покажите, что хотите сделать. А то там довольно громоздкая разметка, что только раздует вопрос и решение, но пользы никакой не даст.

Comment: Примерно [так](http://pastebin.com/yC0cDS3H).Вырезал необходимые участки. Вчера парсил с товарищем на питоне через beatifulsoup, выяснили, что теги расставлены спецефически. На один день распарсили все, что хотели через класс time. там вся информация в одном экземпляре(аудитория, неделя чет\нечет, предмет,преподаватель, название пары). по каждому lesson прогнали во всем дне. и запихали в массив. в итоге? имели подобную конструкцию. day[ ]<lessons[ ]<details [time, week, lesson, name]

Где time - время начала-конца, week - чет\нечет, lesson - название, name - ФИО преподавателя

Comment: Так вопрос ещё актуален, или вы решили поступить иначе?

Comment: Да, все равно придется переделывать под руби все это.На данный момент ищу исчерпывающую документацию по nokogiri

Comment: Тогда приложите **прямо в вопрос** _минимальный_ пример того, на разборе каких данных вы застряли.